# Swagger ui - Query param

Tags: java, rest, swagger, swagger-ui, jersey-1.0

I am using Swagger ui and Swagger core (1.3) for a jersey application. I have certain query parameters which I must send with every request like post, get, delete...

How can I default this ?

Comment: Could you choose a correct response ?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the annotation `@ApiParam` from the Swagger annotations in order to configure the Query param to be used from the Swagger-UI.

For example

```
@Path("/{username}")
@ApiOperation(value = "Updated user")
public Response updateUser(
  @ApiParam(value = "description for query-parameter") @QueryParam("username") String username
) {
...
}
```

Please, read more about this annotation in the following official documentation:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Annotations#apiparam

Comment: ApiParam for queryparam can be used only if the operation has such parameter in its definition. But, here I want to send a Query parameter with the url that will be accessed when a post or get or delete operation is tried out. Hope you understand what I am looking for

Comment: In the scope of the function, check if the variable's value is `null`. If it is, that means the query parameter was not specified in the HTTP request. That is, you can do `if (username == null) { username = "myDefaultValue"; }`.

Answer (score 2):

For swagger version 3, you can use the annotation **@Parameter**

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter
```

https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.0.0-RC3/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/Parameter.html

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but since swagger 2.0 (I don't know if this is supported by swagger-code/swagger-ui), you can defines [parameters to be reuse across operations](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-spec/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#parameters-definitions-object).

For example :

```
{
  "parameters": {
    "pageParam": {
      "name": "page",
      "in": "query",
      "description": "page number to get",
      "required": false,
      "type": "integer",
      "format": "int32"
    }
  },
  "paths": {
    "/customers": {
      "get":  {
        "description": "Retrive list of customers",
        "parameters": {
          "$ref": "#/parameters/pageParam"
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @`Ilya Y`'s answer here's a snippet from a controller I had using `io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;`

```java
@PostMapping("/report")
public FileItem generateReport(
        @RequestParam String projectId,
        @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso = ISO.DATE) @Parameter(schema = @Schema(type = "string", description = "Date in ISO format (yyyy-MM-dd)")) LocalDate date,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "UTC") String zoneId //
) {
...
}
```